# How can I capture as bitmap only what a picturebox is displaying, without using "copy from screen"?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

Specifically: I need to capture as a bitmap a specific region of what a picturebox is actually displaying. The coordinates of the region are specified by the bounds of a control that I have overlayed on top of the picturebox (but that belongs to the picturebox). The control is hidden when I make the "snapshot" of the region.

I tried using normal screen capture methods (CopyFromScreen), but you can't really control the timing there. So it was capturing "interstitial" states, like transitions between photos in my picturebox. Frequently it was only capturing purely black images (the background color of the picture box).

So I tried just converting the image (picturebox.image property) being displayed to a bitmap. The problem there is that the picture box is rarely showing exactly the image.  It's displaying some PORTION of the image, scaled and clipped as appropriate to it's sizemode (which is zoom). So the I can't just take my control coordinates and clip them from the image as a whole.

So I tried to estimate what portion of the image was being displayed, and correcting my rectangle based on that.  Turns out that I was basically re-creating the "zoom" code of the picturebox to do this (using aspect ratio of the picturebox, the aspect ratio of the image, guessing at what level of scaling is currently happening to the image if it's larger or smaller than the picturebox, etc). It was not pretty.

So: now I need a method of just capturing only the bitmap currently being displayed in the client area of the picturebox, including the photo and any black "letterboxing" currently being displayed around it.  Anybody got one?

Remember that I can't rely on using CopyFromScreen.  It's not reliable enough for my purposes.  I think I need a method of getting picturebox to TELL me the bits it is displaying.

Comment: The picture box is running in a different application?

Comment: Some screenshots and code will help illustrate your question.

Comment: @celerno - No, picturebox is in my Winforms app. I'm controlling the photo that goes into it. I have complete access.

Comment: from what i see on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx you have the image property than you can use. Whats wrong with that? And why are you struggling with CopyBits?

Comment: If you want to work on the bit level you can use Bitmap.LockBits(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @IauCosma - See the part that says "So I tried just converting the image being displayed to a bitmap.." It can't serve my purposes, as only some scaled portion of the image is being displayed on screen. And I also explain why I can't use the Screen Capture code which uses CopyFromScreen (sorry, not CopyBits). See the part that starts "So it was capturing "interstitial" states, like transitions between photos..."

Comment: Copy/paste [this method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs#437) into your source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will copy and save the currently shown content of the `PictureBox` including a `BackgroundImage` (if there is one and if it shines through) and also all `Controls` that belong to the `PictureBox`, like `Labels` etc.. Also included are elements drawn in the `Paint` event. Things drawn **outside** the `Paint` event are **non-persistent** and will **not** be included.

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width,
                               pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height))
{
   pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
   bmp.Save(yourfilename, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Note: On my test Form the `PicureBox` is sitting inside an `AutoScroll Panel pan_PBscroll`. The PictureBox is displaying pixels 1:1 and is therefore, with a photograph loaded, much bigger than the Panel, the Form or even the Screen. So to clip to the actually visible parts I could not use the `pictureBox1.ClientSize` and `pictureBox1.ClientRectangle` but used the dimensions of that Panel. This may well apply to you, too.

I'm not sure about your timing issues. But since you mentioned `CopyFromScreen` here are a few differences:

- `CopyFromScreen` makes a 1:1 copy of each screen pixel
- This includes non-persistent drawings and excludes anything covered or hidden
- `Control.DrawToBitmap` makes the Control draw itself onto a Bitmap, just as it draws itself during `Paint`
- This excludes anything that doesn't belong to the Control but includes all members of its Controls collection
- This also excludes non-persistent drawings but includes the full Size of the Control, whether it fits on the Form or Screen or not and whether it is hidden or covered or not.
- For Controls with active Scrollbars only the visible parts are copied. To copy all you need to resize it temporarily. Then you can get a complete image of a listbox even  if it has a thousand items..

Comment: TaW, I know you :-).  Thanks for answering the question actually asked, and not ignoring everything in the post. I'll go try this out asap. By the way, SO won't let me "@Taw" (AtTaw) you. Any idea why?

Comment: @Cardinal Fang: No idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx) I would say to take a look [PictureBox.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can get the [Bitmap object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).

Hope it helps.

Comment: See the part that says "So I tried just converting the image being displayed to a bitmap.." It can't server my purposes, as only some scaled portion of the image is being displayed on screen.