# How to get live frames from a picturebox in C#?

Tags: c#, directx, webcam

I have created an interface in C# which captures video. I also want to  capture images after some interval of time while recording. The video preview runs in a picturebox. Is there any way to capture the frames into images? I have tried many ways including DXsnap but could not get my desired result. 
(NB : Taking screenshot is not applicable as it runs in the background. And I am using directx library to capture the video )

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086374/how-can-i-capture-as-bitmap-only-what-a-picturebox-is-displaying-without-using)

Comment: I have already tried this method and I am getting only white blank image.